# Simulated 741 op amp has unexpectedly small output swing

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt, 741-opamp

While trying to understand the internals of op amps, I tried to implement [a 741 circuit from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Internal_circuitry_of_741-type_op_amp) in LTspice like this: (hooked up as 4x non-inverting amplifier, 0 and 24V supplies, some light output loading)

[image: 741 circuit in LTspice]

DC sweep from 0 to 12 looks like this:

[image: DC sweep]

Well, the gain of 4 is visible at least. But while I certainly did not expect rail-to-rail performance from this circuit, the output bottoms out at 7.12V, and that just seems unreasonable to me. Just to be sure, I tried increasing R14 and R15, but that's not it. Since the output is apparently not really being pulled down, I tried removing Q20, and to my surprise that made no difference. I'd post the DC sweep again, but it's indistinguishable from the one above.

But surely Q20 is there for a reason. Perhaps I wired this up wrong or made some other mistake?

Just to make sure, I independently rebuilt the 741 circuit in a different simulator, not that I'm blaming LTspice of course, but to minimize the chance of me making making the same mistake twice, perhaps due to not understanding the tools. Apologies for the layout and numbering differences.

[image: 741 in EasyEDA]

The exact numbers come out a little bit different (well I didn't put the resistors between the output and the rails this time), but qualitatively the result is similar (orange/brown line is output)

[image]

So, what's going on here? Did I implement the circuit incorrectly both times? Is this actually the right result after all, and the circuit is just that bad? Did I get bitten by my naive assumption that I can just arbitrarily put 2N2222 and 2N2907 as a kind of "default" BJTs?

Comment: my guess is that in the actual 741, there are some transistors with larger or smaller cross sections than others. In particular, I would guess that current sources from current mirrors do not all have identical currents. But this is just a guess.

Comment: Here's [the 741](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsQq1.png). Note the circled area? That's not the *only* difference, either. Carefully look over the real circuit vs your circuit. If interested in more detail, [look here](https://www.righto.com/2015/10/inside-ubiquitous-741-op-amp-circuits.html). Be very, very careful about what you imagine as the real IC circuit vs what you are simulating!

Comment: @jonk apparently the schematic I followed was based on the one shown in the [LM741 manual](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) which is apparently a bit different, but it's still supposed to be an op amp circuit

Comment: @harold That's because the datasheets provide ***behavioral*** diagrams. They get the point across. But they do NOT disclose ***all*** of the details.

Comment: @jonk fair enough I'll try to replicate that other circuit then

Comment: @harold LTspice can certainly simulate the LM741, accurately. Linear uses LTspice for internal IC simulation purposes. And since that is ***very important*** to them, it *just works right*. The problem will be in getting the details down right. I'd recommend either visiting the [LTspice users' group site](https://groups.io/g/LTspice) (probably they have a simulation model there already) or else just writing to key people at the site and asking for help. Chances are, you'll get help. They are very nice people.

Comment: @harold Now that I'm looking, I see lots of simulation options at the LTspice users group site. Not sure which is meant to be closest to the original design. Too many to read through to figure that out. But there are lots of them there. Worth checking out.

Comment: @harold There already is a transistor level example in the default installation: open `My Documents/LTspiceXVII/examples/Educational/LM741.asc` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For your information,

From microcap12 files, 741 modeling ...
DC Analysis, dual supply +15 V/-15 V, open loop.

Added models used.

.MODEL DD D (CJO=2P RS=1.5)
.MODEL QPL PNP (**BF=10** CJC=4P CJE=6P RB=20 VAF=50 TF=1N TR=20N )
.MODEL QNL NPN (BF=80 CJC=2P CJE=3P RB=100 VAF=50 TF=300P TR=6N CJS=2P)

[image]

Comment: +1 Those lateral PNP transistors are real dogs.

Comment: Yes. There are :-). Should I add also AC analysis for reference?

Comment: could you improve your answer and explain how the terrible PNPs help to extend output swing?

Comment: Will try first change BF ... But don't know how the "results" would be (for now).

Comment: No change ... Just added a little offset voltage (about -200uV)